# sklearn Group K-fold and groups parameters in other cross-validators similarity

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

Maybe it is obvious but I would like to be sure of what I am doing:

I understand that Group K-fold implemented in sklearn, is a variation of k-fold cross validation where it is ensured that data belonging to the same group will not be represented in train and sets at the same time.

That is what I also need. However, before I discover the aforementioned implementation of group k-fold, as i was trying to calculate the validation curve concerning a problem, I noticed the following parameter (the highlighted one):

***validation_curve***(estimator, X, y, param_name, param_range, **groups**=None, cv=None...)

According to the documentation if I provide a list of size [n_samples] providing the labels for the corresponding groups, then train/test dataset splitting will be done according to these labels.

And here comes the question. Since a such convenient variable is provided, why - according to my searches- everyone in need of group k-fold validation is first using sklearn.model_selection.**GroupKFold** ?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you clarify more? What convenient variable are you talking about? The `groups` param in the `validation_curve` or everywhere?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. Yes i am talking about the `groups` parameter, thats why i highlighted the specific one. And my question is, simply said, if this parameter is actually doing what GroupKfold is built to do. Because GroupKfold is also provided with the test dataset, the labels for prediction (that is X, y) and a vector of labels that represent the group each datapoint belongs to.